# Host WiFi connection not working when VM is on

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have a Kali VM on VMWare and when I have it on the VM's internet connection works, but my host machine's doesn't

The VM is using a bridged network adapter and my host machine is a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I did was simple all I did was change the adapter to NAT.